# DELETEしてもFMDBファイルのサイズが小さくなりません

Tags: ios, database

DELETEしてもFMDBのファイル（xxx.sqlite）サイズが小さくなりません。

解決策の１つとして、新規のsqliteファイルを作りそこに必要な分だけインサートでコピーすれば最小のサイズのファイルが出来るかと思いました。

しかしこの方法ですと処理に時間がかかってしまうので困っています。

何かいい方法はありませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

すみません。自己解決しました。
VACUUM;コマンドですね。
失礼しました。